# How to handle two scroll events in a webpage

Tags: javascript, events

two js function loads on scroll . Say there is two onscroll events to handle

```
window.onscroll = function(e) {
  var footerHeight = 500;
  if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY + footerHeight) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
    if (branchLoaded == false) {
      loadBranch1();
    };
  }
};

window.onscroll = function(e) {
  var footerHeight = 500;
  if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY + footerHeight) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
    if (branchLoaded == false) {
      loadBranch2();
    };
  }
};
```

Comment: Try `addEventListener`

Comment: In your current code, everything is same except the function you're invoking. That's not the correct usage of multiple event listener

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, the second event handler is overriding the first one.

This is similar to `<element onload="function(){}" onload="function(){}">`. In it, Only the latter one will execute.

#### Example

```js
window.onscroll = function(){console.log(1)}
window.onscroll = function(){console.log(2)}
```

```html
<div>Test<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>Bottom</div>
```

#### Solution

You need [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to set up multiple Event Listener.

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll',function(){console.log(1)});
window.addEventListener('scroll',function(){console.log(2)});
```

```html
<div>Test<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>Bottom</div>
```